# Что такое dns-prefetch и x-dns-prefetch-control?

Tags: html, производительность, оптимизация-сайтов

Решил подробнее изучить тему мета-тэгов и наткнулся на такие тэги:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="on">
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="">
```

Как работают и какую задачу они решают?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Кратко - Вы сообщаете браузеру, по каким адресам могут находиться ресурсы Вашей страницы (картики, скрипты), что бы он мог разрезолвить имена сразу. На очень медленном интернете это может сэкономить до 0.2 секунд на каждый запрос.

Comment: KoVadim, спасибо за ответ. Могли Вы более подробно описать процесс работы? Например у меня есть две картинки в html

img(src="test.ru/image-1.jpg")
img(src="test.ru/image-2.jpg")

Когда он первый раз встречает test.ru он его резолвит. Когда он встречает его второй раз он резолвит его снова или результат закэшируется? Или я все не так понимаю?

Comment: второй раз браузер скорее всего воспользуется закешированным результатом. Более того, он скорее всего будет им пользовать ещё какое-то время, даже после обновления страницы или перехода на другую страницу.

Comment: Извините за глупость, но что дает prefetch? Ведь при первом обращении адрес резолвится и результат кэшируется.

Comment: очень простой пример. Допустим у Вас на сайте галерея и картинки подгружаются динамически с десятка различных сайтов (например, карты. Сайты различные, так как cdn - разложили по разным сайтам, что бы оптимизировать нагрузку).

Как только пользователь выполнит заданное действие и браузер будет вынужден подгрузить картинку, ему нужно будет разрезолвить адрес. А это может вызывать определенные лаги. Если же браузеру сразу указать возможные адреса, то он их может закешировать (тех нескольких секунд, пока пользователь смотрел на сайт хватит). И эти лаги можно уменьшить.

Comment: Действительно, про динамический контент я не подумал. Использование prefetch для динамического контента мне кажется логичным, а для статичных картинок нет. Спасибо.

Comment: @KoVadim, похоже, что ссылка которая тут была - протухла. Я её потёр в данный момент из ответа. Будет круто, если вы ответ поправите, найдя новую ссылку или дописав ответ)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а можно ссылку на вебархив добавить? Думаю она долго там лежать будет...  http://web-arhive.ru/view?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwebperformance.ru%2F2012%2F01%2F23%2Fpreloading%2F&time=20150404134713&f=1

Comment: @byVerng, подойдёт любая ссылка с нужной инфой) Если же оттуда информацию в ответ перенести - вообще чудесно будет, ибо не надо будет за ссылкой следить)